# Exe files created by GCC have no permission?

Tags: gcc, permissions, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a simple hello world code in c++. Mingw, Dev c++ with mingw, Code::Blocks (with compiler again). When i try to compile and execute, an exe is created and executed. But when i try to compile again (overwrite to same output file) i got an error: "Permission denied".

The file i am trying to overwrite is not running, i am sure. But when i check the permissions for file, it says: "You don't have permissions to see permission for this object". I am running everthing in administrator mode, my account is administrator, if i do not have the rights, who has?

And the created exe files are delete themselves after a time period.

I have no idea what is going on. I don't have any other problems with other files/programs/permissions, antivirus found nothing. Is anyone have any idea?

Edit: OS is Win7.

Answer (score 0):

There could be one of a few things wrong.  First, it might be open somewhere.  You can download Process Explorer and check if any programs have open handles to it.  You can close the programs, or the handles, and then try to delete it again.  Alternatively, the problem could be related to permissions - it might be someone elses file.  Right click -> properties -> security tab -> advanced -> owner tab, and take ownership of the object.  There may be additional buttons if you are using Vista/7 and have UAC enabled.

Process Explorer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: I tried Process Explorer, no signs of my exe. About taking permissions; it is not an actual solution. Because everytime i compile the code, new file has no permissions again.

Comment: Does it work? if it does then perhaps investigation as to why could solve the issue.  It would be weird the creator of the file would end up with no permissions though.

Comment: It is not working. I get "Access denied" error. Both from console and GUI.

Comment: Weird, something must still have a handle open to it somewhere.  How are you terminating your program?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h> 
main() { 
 printf("Hello World!\n");
 return 0;
}`

Comment: how utterly bizarre.  try a different compiler maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and I solved it by removing "redundant" g++ mentions of included files. Somehow g++ can automatically induce some included files and then when you try to compile them with the g++ command they are locked by the automatic include compilation... geez!